# buttons turn blue when backgroundimage is set

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a few buttons and when I set a picture as background the icons turn blue, for example:

```
[self.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

All pictures are black and white, so I don't understand why they change their color when I set them as a backgroundimage.

Comment: Try change titnColor of your button.

Comment: Already tried that, didn't work.

Comment: try setBackgroundImage instead setImage

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure to init the button as a "UIButtonTypeCustom"

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

Then if you want the whole button to be an image, you use:

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

... Or if you want to have the image as the background, and still see the "title", you use:

```
 [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Key part of this for me was setting the button as custom

Answer (score 0):

First do

```
self.button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

and then set image

```
[self.button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```